# crontab doesn't work when time is specified

Tags: cron, ibm, aix

In my AIX server, the cron job runs fine when specified to run every minute.

```
* * * * * echo "test" >> /home/myUser/testLog.log
```

But it doesn't work when a specific time is given.

```
* 16 * * * echo "test" >> /home/myUser/testLog.log
```

Please note I've checked below:

1. The server time is after 16
2. The mail file doesn't show any errors (it does if there are any other errors, such as a permission issue)
3. There are no other logs that I could find to debug, such as /var/logs/cron or syslog.

Comment: "The server time is after 16" -- You mean it is after 16 but before 17, right?

Comment: @Lacek Yes it's before 17

Comment: Is your server time equal to the localtime or UTC? What is the output of the `date`?

Comment: @kondybas It's local time. Server time was 16.20 at the time.

Comment: I would check what hour gets appended if you write `* * * * * date >> /home/myUser/testLog.log`

Comment: Was the time zone recently changed, e.g. for some sort of daylight savings adjustment? If so, and the server was not restarted, the cron daemon may be running under the old/previous timezone.